# Select text with double click is selecting wrong text

Tags: html, css, angularjs

So I have a web application that has a panel area. This area contains a text that can be copied to the clipboard. The problem is that every time I select this text (with 3 left button clicks) the text from the button bellow is also selected.

[image]

From the image above, if I select the TEXT TO COPY and Ctrl+C I will get the following clipboard (which is wrong):

> TEXT TO COPY
>
> CLICK ME

This is the HTML code where this is inserted.

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body wrapped-pannel">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>TEXT TO COPY</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
    
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary"
                    ng-show="canclick">
                CLICK ME
            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-default">
                BACK
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Can anyone understand why is this happening? Many thanks.

Comment: The buttons without type will be **"submit"** by default  so... you are submitting the form on each click. Just put **type="button"** to each button

Comment: @Roy Yeah but that is not the problem :\

Comment: Your example is working fine for me.